# PHP MYSQL ARRAY check if string is in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have user input which in this case will be Hello

```
$command = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['command']);
```

a variable called $dialogue_unlock is populated through some scripts. Which for testing will output 'Hello','Goodbye'

```
$dialogue_unlock .= ',\''. $discuss_row['discussion_text'].'\'';
```

Im then trying to see if the user input matches the array

```
$dialogue_array = array($dialogue_unlock);
if(!in_array("$command", $dialogue_array)){
    $err .= 'Invalid Question';
}
```

As a test im using

```
echo $err. '<br>';
echo $command. '<br>';
echo $dialogue_unlock;
```

I get

```
Invalid Question
Hello
'Hello','Goodbye'
```

I just cant wrap my head around it as 'hello' is definitely in 'Hello','Goodbye'. Can anybody offer some advise please.

Many thanks.

Comment: If I understood what you need to do, you have to explode the dialogue_unlock string to get an array of each comma separated value `$dialogue_array = explode(",", $dialogue_unlock);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though your array contains the 1 element with the text `'Hello','Goodbye'` and when you look for `Hello` it doesn't match.  What you should do is add each item of `$discuss_row['discussion_text']` to `$dialogue_array` directly using (in whatever loop you build up `$dialogue_unlock`)

```
$dialogue_array[] = $discuss_row['discussion_text'];
```

So when you add `Hello` and `Goodbye` then it will be two separate elements in the array.

Just make sure that before this loop you initialise the array...

```
$dialogue_array = [];
```

Comment: You've no idea how much annoyance you saved me. Cant believe i was silly enough to go about this the complete wrong way. That works exactly as i need it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$command = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['command']); /// hello
$dialogue_unlock .= ',\''. $discuss_row['discussion_text'].'\''; /// 'Hello','Goodbye'
$dialogue_unlock = explode(',', $dialogue_unlock); /// dialogue_unlock to array


foreach ($dialogue_unlock as $a) {
    if (strpos($command, $a) !== FALSE) { 
        echo "Match found"; 
    }
   else
    {
        echo "Not found!";
    }
}
```